# How to prove that reduced suspension $\Sigma X=S^1 \wedge X$ of a pointed space $(X,x_0)$ is an H-cogroup

Tags: homotopy-theory

Question is in the title: How to prove that reduced suspension $\Sigma X=S^1 \wedge X$ (smash product) of pointed space $(X,x_0)$ (and $S^1$) is an $H$-cogroup?

Comment: Use the tensor-hom adjunction.

Comment: Could you be more specific, please. I'm not familiar with tensor-hom adjunction.

Comment: At least when your spaces are all compactly generated and weak Hausdorff or something like that, the based mapping spaces satisfy the *functorial* relation $map_*(X \wedge Y,Z) \cong map_*(X,map_*(Y,Z))$.  (Here, smash product is a "tensor product", and the based mapping space is the "internal hom".)